# No feedback if sql insert succeeded

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I'm performing following scenario :
When I press a button I insert this into the database and that's working. But i don't get feedback if it succeeded or not (the alerts wont pop up). But if I look in my database it is inserted

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] > 3) 
    {
    $message = 'success';
    $message1 = 'failed';
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $values = $_POST['action'];
        $status = 'pending';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (value, status) VALUES ('".$values."', '".$status."')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>alert("<?php echo $message; ?>");</script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>alert("<?php echo $message1; ?>");</script>
<?php }                                    
    }       
    }
?>
```

This is the button and inputfield I use to insert the value in the database:

```
<input type="text" id="number"><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="test" onclick="myAjax(number.value);">test</button>
```

and this is the ajax call:

```
function myAjax(value) {


  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'test.php',
       data:{action:value},
       dataType: 'text',
       success: function(data) {

       }

  });
}
```

Comment: You tagged `AJAX` are you using ajax or a form? (you also are open to SQL injections with this..)

Comment: @chris85 I have edited my question, now the AJAX is included, and yeah thanks I have to look at prepared statements I guess :)

Comment: Write the filenames above your code so we understand whats happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did it with a workaround, not really how I wanted it but its working now so. Basically I handled it in the Ajax success function instead of  in the php file.

instead of this

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] > 3) 
    {
    $message = 'success';
    $message1 = 'failed';
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $values = $_POST['action'];
        $status = 'pending';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (value, status) VALUES ('".$values."', '".$status."')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo $message; 
} else { 
echo $message1;
}                                    
    }       
    }
?>
```

And this

```
function myAjax(value) {


  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'test.php',
       data:{action:value},
       dataType: 'text',
       success: function(data) {

       }

  });
}
```

I now have this :

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] > 3) 
    {
    $message = 'success';
    $message1 = 'failed';
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $values = $_POST['action'];
        $status = 'pending';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (value, status) VALUES ('".$values."', '".$status."')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {}                                    

    }
?>
```

and this :

```
function myAjax(value) {




    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'test.php',
           data:{action:value},
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function(data) {
           if(value > 3 && value != undefined && value != "")
           {
            alert("working");
           }
            else
           {
            alert("not working");
           }
               }

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Return the status to the AJAX call then handle the response in there.

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] > 3) 
    {
    $message = 'success';
    $message1 = 'failed';
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $values = $_POST['action'];
        $status = 'pending';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (value, status) VALUES ('".$values."', '".$status."')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo $message; 
} else { 
echo $message1;
}                                    
    }       
    }
?>
```

Then in JS:

```
function myAjax(value) {


  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'test.php',
       data:{action:value},
       dataType: 'text',
       success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
       }

  });
}
```

Also look into using prepared statements, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php, to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: Instead of posting my own answer, I'll follow up on this one. This is in fact the correct answer, and the reason why it's not working is because jQuery does NOT run scripts that are returned in the HTML of AJAX methods.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks that worked :) How can I alert message or message1? because now its alerting the whole page or something?

Comment: And I dont see the echo

Comment: @Nick What is the response on the AJAX call, not just `success`? Use the developer console to see the response being returned.

Comment: @chris85 I dont see anything poping up in console, so i guess no response?

Comment: Open the developer console and check. You said it worked, how did it work?

Comment: @chris85 Yeah i tought it worked because i saw an alert but its the alert(data) that popped up, i opened the dev console and there is no response

Comment: replace `alert` to `console.log`, open the developer console and see what is being returned. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: @chris85 Uhm I replaced alert(data) to console.log(data) and I get the whole page code I think as html.

Comment: @Nick whats the status here?

Comment: @chris85 Instead of alerting  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) because that didnt work, I now have moved everything to AJAX success function so its kinda working now but with a different approach :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You should follow up on your threads though. If you resolved it and the answer wasn't here you should post it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your ajax success does nothing.

In PHP:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Failure";
}
```

In JS:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'test.php',
   data: {action:value},
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The last } will not close any code block in your example. the if dont need a === TRUE, just  if ($conn->query($sql)), if the query feedback is true the if will be true.

something like this:

```
    <?
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] > 3) {

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $values = $_POST['action'];
        $status = 'pending';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (value, status) VALUES ('".$values."', '".$status."')";

        if ($conn->query($sql)) {
            echo 'succes';
        } else { 
            echo 'fail';        
        }                                    
    }       

    ?>
```

and your js like:

```
    function myAjax(value) {


      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'test.php',
           data:{action:value},
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
           }

      });
    }
```